# Wix Toolset execution of Powershell-script does not work

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

I want to run a PowerShell-Script before and after the installation with the msi-file. Below you can see the basic content of my configuration in Visual Studio 2013 for wix-project. The msi is compiled without errors and I can run the msi-file and go through the steps till the end of installation without errors.

In the log I can see, that the CustomAction had been started, but this cannot be true because the directory that should have been created by the underlying script has not been created.

If I run the script-file manually by powershell everything runs well. So the script itself should work and does not throw an error.

Any suggestions what is wrong here?

Wix-Project:

```
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyAPP" Language="1031" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="2A0A9FDB-9DD2-4058-8742-885EF63BFF37">
    <!-- 6e8e53ce-66e4-4d97-900c-9678b83e44cc"> -->
    <Package InstallerVersion="400" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Languages="1031" Manufacturer="Me" Description="Installiert den MyApp auf ihr System" Comments="NOTHING TO COMMENT"/>
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!-- Major Upgrade Rule to disallow downgrades -->
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Eine neuere Version vom [ProductName] ist bereits installiert." />

    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- Aktionen vor installation ##########-->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="StartBatchFile" After="InstallInitialize"/>
      <Custom Action="EndBatchFile" After="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    <CustomAction Id="StartBatchFile"
              Property="RegisterHttpModulePowerShellProperty"
              Value="&quot;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -Version 2.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File &quot;./BeforeInstallationScript.ps1&quot; &quot;[DIR_ComponentRef]&quot;"
              Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="EndBatchFile"
              Property="RegisterHttpModulePowerShellProperty"
              Value="&quot;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; o-Versin 2.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File &quot;./AfterInstallationScript.ps1&quot; &quot;[DIR_ComponentRef]&quot;"
              Execute="immediate" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="WixUIBannerBmp.bmp" />
    <!--    Background bitmap used on the welcome and completion dialogs    493 × 312 -->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="WixUIDialogBmp.bmp" />

    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- User-Interface ####################-->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR">DIR_ComponentRef</Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- Notwendige Abhaengigkeiten ########-->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
    <Condition Message="Diese Anwendung benoetigt .NET Framework 4.0. Bitte installieren sie zuerst das .NET Framework und starten Sie die Installation erneut.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
    </Condition>

    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- FEATURE-Installation ##############-->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <Feature Id="FEATURE_MyApp" Title="MyApp" Description="Installiert die Datein des MyApps auf das System" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" ConfigurableDirectory="DIR_ComponentRef">
      <ComponentRef Id="[...]"/>
      [...]
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- Ordner-Struktur ################### -->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="DIR_ComponentRef" Name="MyApp">
            <Directory Id="DIR_CONFIGURATION" Name="configuration">
              [...]
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    [...]
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <!-- Componenten-Definition ######## -->
    <!-- ################################### -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="DIR_ComponentRef">
      <Component Id="CMP_MyApp.exe">
        <File Id="MyApp.exe" Source="$(var.SourcePath)MyApp.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
      </Component>
      [...]
    </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Log-Result:

```
=== Protokollierung gestartet: 16.11.2016  10:41:12 ===
Aktion 10:41:12: INSTALL. 
[...]
Aktion 10:41:35: StartBatchFile. 
Aktion gestartet um 10:41:35: StartBatchFile.
Aktion beendet um 10:41:35: StartBatchFile. Rückgabewert 1.
[...]
Aktion beendet um 10:41:38: InstallFinalize. Rückgabewert 1.
Aktion 10:41:38: EndBatchFile. 
Aktion gestartet um 10:41:38: EndBatchFile.
Aktion beendet um 10:41:38: EndBatchFile. Rückgabewert 1.
Aktion beendet um 10:41:38: INSTALL. Rückgabewert 1.
[...]
```

Let me know if you need further informations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `CustomAction`can find the PS1 file under the local directory. Try to adapt the WIX file with following blocks

```
 <!-- Ensure PowerShell is installed and obtain the PowerShell executable location -->
<Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                  Type="raw"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                  Name="Path" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="This application requires Windows PowerShell.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLEXE]]>
</Condition>

....

<CustomAction Id="RegisterPowershellCommandStop"
              Property="CallPowerShellCommandStop"
              Value="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]ServiceStartStop.ps1&quot; &quot;[SERVICENAME]&quot; &quot;stop&quot;"
              Execute="immediate" />

....
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
   <Component Id="CMP_StartStopServicesScript" Guid="*">
      <File Id="FILE_StartStopServicesScript" Source="!(wix.binDirectory)\ServiceStartStop.ps1" KeyPath ="yes" />
   </Component>
...
```

In this case we're calling PS ("stored" in `[POWERSHELLEXE]`to start `ServiceStartStop.ps1` (located under `[INSTALLDIR]`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That means, that I need to copy the ps-scripts into the same folder as the msi-file lies and cannot inbound it directly into the msi-file as a resource?

Comment: No you don't need to copy the ps1 files seperately to the target. The ps1 scripts are "inside" the MSI package, will be installed on the target, and afterwards called via the `CustomAction`.

Comment: I'm struggling with that. The script-files are copied correctly to the desired location on local system now. But it might be too late, because I need those files before I'm deleting old installed files on system. Anyway, I still cannot see, that the script is executed. Why I can see that? the second time I start the installer the files from previous installation-execution are still there and the script does not create the directory as I expect to be created by the script.